# Удалить в проекте не используемые стили из css файла

Tags: ide, css

Подскажите есть ли какой-нибудь софт или плагин к Visual Studio 2008, чтобы удалить стили из css файла, которые не используется в разметке проекта? Так же нужно удалить картинки из папки images, которые я не использую в проекте. А то у меня такой бардак...

Comment: а просто удалить эти стили нельзя, так скажем "руками"?

Comment: так сказать - по старинке :)<br>
 не факт что вообще есть такие возможности, откуда VS будет знать о всех однозначно неиспользуемых картинках и css лично мне непонятно...

Comment: По старинке нужно день возиться с этим. А что сложного, распарсить все классы и id, которые есть в разметках на страницах и сравнить с css файлом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нет, к сожалению, а скорее даже к счастью такой вещи нет, к примеру, у меня есть index.php куда инклюдятся файлы из глубины 2-3-4 каталога... этот монстр хотябы  в моём случае должен поддерживать "проект" и сам разбираться в моём коде(я сам то теряюсь иногда) и вот.. я решу почистить style.css который лежит в папке css и линкуется к индексу... а страницы к индексу привязываются через include(php)... я донёс свою мысль?
ЗЫ конечно желательно стайл.ксс отбекапить) а то он мне 90% файла почистит, скажет "На главное странице такого нет, а больше я никуда не подключаюсь"